# Экспорт бд MySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка. Пытаюсь сделать экспорт бд `MySQL` таким способом

```
mysqldump -u name_userdb -p -h localhost name_base > dump.sql
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Для Windows:**

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server\bin\mysqldump.exe" --user=root --password="123" --database name_base >D:\arh\dump20130731.sql
```

Где:

- name_base - имя экспортируемой базы
- D:\arh\dump20130731.sql – путь и имя файла для сохранения базы

**Для Linux:**

```
mysqldump --user=root --password="123" --database name_base >/home/username/arh/dump20130731.sql
```

Eсли нужно импортировать/экспортировать несколько баз в одном файле-архиве, тогда просто перечислите имена баз через пробел, например:

```
mysqldump --user=root --password="123" --database name_base another_base  >/home/username/arh/dump20130731.sql
```

Comment: Я использую для Линукса первый случай, но не работает, какого пользователя с паролем я должен указать?

Comment: Что ж такое... @Sergey4590, если вам надо с полными правами, то естественно **root**.

Запускамся, входя с root-правми

    путь_к > mysql.exe -u root -p [Enter]
    Enter password: (пусто, если пароль не задан)[Enter]
    Welcome ...

Всё! Зашли с полными правами и тварим, что хотим: дамп, дроп, пиво. Если пароль для root устанавливали, то его и пишем при входе.

Answer (score 0):

**mysqldump --opt --user=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD DATABASE TABLENAME > TO BASE**

Comment: Че то не то, мне надо бд в файл засунуть, а не наоборот.